# Cant Make the Image fit Parent Element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm new to bootstrap 4. I'm trying to build a responsive website using bootstrap for practice. I have an issue with my image not resizing to fit the screen.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required Meta Data -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstraps CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <!-- Custome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

    <title>Museum of Candy</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-dark  navbar-expand-md py-0 fixed-top">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">CANDY</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="navLinks" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUR</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">TICKETS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>        
    </nav>

    <section class="container-fluid px-0">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="text-white text-center d-none d-lg-block">
                    <h2 class="">MUSEUM OF CANDY</h2>
                    <h2 class="">MUSEUM OF CANDY</h2>
                    <h2 class="">MUSEUM OF CANDY</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 px-0">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="imgs/img1.jpg" alt="Hand Donut">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- JQuery First, Then Popper.js, then Bottstarp JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this my image is not covering the entire column space and leaving a portion.
[image: this is image at full size]

even when i resize the screen to medium resolution image is not covering full screen

[image: Image not leaving extra space in medium screen]

when i try to add css to it they are being crossed of.

CSS File

```
body{
    background: #f5d9d5;
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}



#mainNavbar{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 100;
}

#mainNavbar .nav-link{
    color: white;
}

#mainNavbar .nav-link:hover{
    color: #EA1C2C;
}

#mainNavbar .navbar-brand{
    color: #EA1C2C;
}
```

Comment: Where is your CSS ?

Comment: Please add **app.css** in this question @Abhishek varma

Comment: added app.css.. please look into to it

Comment: Its weird but your code is working fine with my IE, Firefox and Chrome. Image sitting on right and there is no extra space.  Even on resizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img class="img-fluid" style="float:right;" width="100%" src=...>
```

This will make the image fit the parent div
and should probably solve your issue

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer a bit more so it can help other users in the future? What have you changed and how does it work.

Comment: i didnt change anything yet. I havent found a solution for this